# Collection not firing listen events

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

In my backbone collection I am working with a collection view at the moment, the view is generated "on the fly".

I am struggling to get the view to update when something is added to the collection, on debugging I have noticed that the collection does not have a `_listenid` which in my limited knowledge I assume means it cannot listen for the events bound to it?

What would this be happening?

Here is my view,

```
 Pops.Views.ProjectManagers = Backbone.View.extend({

    className: 'ui-user-list ui-user-list--single',

    template: _.template($("#tpl-project-managers").html()),

    events: {
        "click .js-add-user": "addUser"
    },

    initialize: function () {

        // this.collection.on('all', function() {
        //     console.log(arguments);
        // });

        // this.collection.on('reset', this.render, this);
        console.log(this.collection);
        this.collection.on('add', this.addOneProjectManager, this);
    },

    render: function () {
        //alert("!!!!!");
        this.$el.html(this.template());
        this.addAllProjectManagers();
        return this;
    },

    addAllProjectManagers: function () {
        this.collection.each(this.addOneProjectManager, this);
    },

    addOneProjectManager: function (model) {
        console.log(model);
        if(this.model.get('is_admin') == true) {
            model.set('admin', true);
        }

        var teamMember = new App.Views.SingleTeamMember({
            model: model,
            project: this.model
        });

        this.$('.ui-member-list').prepend(teamMember.render().el);
    },
});
```

If I physically refresh the page, the collection then has a `_listenid`

I initialise this view like this,

```
var projectManagerList = new Pops.Views.ProjectManagers({
        model      : this.model,
        collection : this.model.get('project_manager')
    });
```

and this is the model I pass through,

[image: The model]

Comment: Please post the code instantiating/using your View

Comment: Please see update @hindmost

Comment: I don't understand what you exactly mean by `_listenid`, but with Views it's always better to use [`listenTo`](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-listenTo) instead of [`on`]: `this.listenTo(this.collection, 'add', this.addOneProjectManager);`

Comment: this.collection will not bind listeners until I refresh the app.

Comment: Is anything added to your collection after your view has been rendered ? Could you post your collection code ?

Comment: when you create your view have you verified that you are really passing the model and collections ? no scope problem ? new view({ collection:self.collection ... ?